# Javascript: IIfe called before class constructor

Tags: javascript, iife

So I was just playing around with javascript, I have an iife defined withing a class which is being called before the class constructor.

```js
class SomeClass {
  constructor() {
    console.log('Constructor Called.');
  };

  someIife = (() => {
    console.log('iife called');
    return () => { }
  })()
};

const someClass = new SomeClass();
```

The output is -

> iife called
>
> Constructor Called.

Is this by design?
I am not sure what is happening.

Seems really interesting, could someone please explain why is this happening.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The constructor function that's generated from your class declaration is effectively this:

```
  function SomeClass() {
    this.someIife = (() => {
      console.log('iife called');
      return () => { 

      }
    })();
    console.log("constructor called");
  }
```

Instance variable declarations in the `class` body are transformed into `this.something` initializations in the constructor function body. Those initializations happen before the actual constructor body, so that the instance values can be used by the constructor code.

Comment: It helps me personally to be not confused by thinking of `class` declarations as being like a "macro" in other languages.

Comment: Well, shouldnt `console.log("constructor called")` be above `this.someIide` ?

Comment: @AmolGupta no, because the code in the constructor body should expect that all the instance properties have already been initialized.

Comment: Oh, seems like a chicken and egg problem, thanks a lot anyway.

Comment: @AmolGupta personally I think the feature is awkward too.